# Terraform code is failing and throwing error when I query available provider package -> AZAPI

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I am trying to use the Azure/Azapi Provider within my Terraform project to create Key Vault's key rotation policy but after I add the provider and run terraform init, I get the following error alternatively:

#1
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing azure/azapi v0.1.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/azure/azapi: failed to
│ retrieve authentication checksums for provider: 403 Forbidden

#2
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing azure/azapi v0.1.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/azure/azapi: failed to
│ retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the request failed after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get
│ "https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi/releases/download/v0.1.0/terraform-provider-azapi_0.1.0_SHA256SUMS": net/http:
│ request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

#This is how my providers.tf look like,

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azuread" {
}

provider "azapi" {
}
```

This how my versions.tf looks like,

`

```
`terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.7.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "2.29.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
      version = "=0.1.0"
    }
  }
}`
```

`

Do you guys have any idea why its failing to install the azapi provider and rest azurerm, azuread are working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

After I've done a workaround, the problem is happening due to one of these reasons:

1.

> [Given by @Anton Akulov](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/5177241219859-Terraform-init-Error-while-installing-provider-Failed-to-retrieve-authentication-checksums-for-provider) Make sure the machine has your root CA certificate in the store when proxy server used with the terraform. Error occurs if machine where terraform is running doesn't have valid certificate for the proxy server.

2. 

> All Downloads are 403 Forbidden due to [registry outage of hashicorp](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/6298)

[Refer for more](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/29775)

So, I have tried in Azure cloud bash (cli):

*Installed Azapi provider by creating a file main.tf in `azCLI` with command* `vi main.tf`

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "1.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azapi" {
  features{} #configuration
}
```

*Though I installed the latest published version (1.0.0), I've encountered an error as shown below:*

[image]

*To resolve this error, I've used `terraform init --upgrade` and run `terraform init` and it worked successfully*.

[image]

[Terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Azure/azapi/1.0.0)

Comment: Hello @Jahnavi, thanks for the help but unfortunately I am still getting the same error.
Now, what i did is,
I downloaded _"terraform-provider-azapi_v1.0.0"_ file and placed it into the .terraform folder like this - 
_"\.terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\azure\azapi\1.0.0"_

Comment: What is the error you are getting. Could you share here?

Comment: Did you follow the same process and still getting an error? Could you elaborate!

Comment: then I tried to run _"terraform init -get=false"_ but still same error, _"Error: Failed to install provider Error while installing azure/azapi v1.0.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/azure/azapi: failed to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: 403 Forbidden returned from"_? Is approach right, execution wrong?

Comment: Just trying that terraform stop fetching the plugin and instead use the file i have manually provided

Comment: As I mentioned in the above answer, failed to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: 403 Forbidden occurs because of registry issue and it is restricting to get the azapi provider. Can you do the same process again after some time because it might be coming because of server loading issue.

Comment: Before retrieving the new version of provider, delete the existing one and try.